# Normal subgroup of classical groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

For $r\leq n$, consider the following reduction homomorphism 
$$
\pi_{n,r}: {\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/(p^n\mathbb{Z}))\to {\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/(p^r\mathbb{Z})).
$$
Bourgain and Gamburd in their paper "Expansion and random walks in ${\rm SL}_d(\Bbb Z/(p^n
\Bbb Z))$" mentioned that the set

$$\{\ker\pi_{n,r}\},$$

gives all normal subgroups of ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb Z/(p^n\Bbb Z))$. Probably this is standard, but I am not able to prove it.

Can any one please give me a hint or a reference for this fact?

I remember that I read somewhere that a modification of  this fact also valid for 
$${\rm SL}_k(\mathbb{Z}/(p^n\mathbb{Z})),$$

and the symplectic group 
$${\rm Sp}_{2k}(\mathbb{Z}/(p^n\mathbb{Z}).$$
But I can not find where I saw these. I would be most thankful if anyone can help me with these.

Comment: I'm guessing you really mean "unable to prove it"

Comment: You (at least) also have all subgroups of the group of scalar matrices.

Comment: @Geoff: Yes, I meant "I am not able". Thanks.

Comment: ... as well as some inverse images of groups of scalar matrices (e.g. the normal subgroup consisting of matrices whose reduction modulo $p^r$ is scalar). Note that for $k=p=2$ and $n>2$, the scalar matrices are not only plus and minus identity, since $x^2=1$ has 4 solutions in $Z/2^nZ$. If your question is whether every normal subgroup is obtained this way, you should edit accordingly.

Comment: @Yves: Thanks for your comment. Here I assume $p$ is a big prime number. 

Comment: But my first comment as well as the first part of my comment applies for all $p$: you have inverse images of scalar matrices mod $p^r$.

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 7.5 in Bass, Milnor, Serre, Solution of the congruence subgroup problem for $SL_n$, (n≥3) and $Sp_{2n}$, (n≥2). 

Comment: @Wilbert: this theorem is for $SL_k$ for $k\ge 3$. Precisely it states that every normal subgroup is the inverse image of a central subgroup in some reduction mod $p^r$. 

Comment: @Ives I know, and yet, when you look what what they actually do you find it instructive for the case at hand too. In any case it provides a hook for searching the literature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me answer the question for $p>3$ and $SL_2$. I imagine that a similar method will work for the other cases but I haven't checked.

Some notation: $G=SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$, $Z=\{I, -I\}$ and, for $i=1,\dots, n$,
$$K_i := \ker \pi_{n,i}.$$

**Proposition**: The proper normal subgroups of $G$ are $K_i$ and $K_i\times Z$ for $i=1,\dots, n$.

**Sketch of basic steps of proof**:

- If $n=1$, $G$ is quasisimple and the result is immediate. Assume from here on that $n>1$.
- Observe that $K_1$ is a normal
  $p$-subgroup of $G$, that
  $|K_1|=p^{3(n-1)}$ and $G/K_1\cong
     SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, a
  quasisimple group since $p>3$.
- Observe, next that, for $i=1,\dots,
     n$, |$K_i| = p^{3(n-i)}$ and,
  moreover, $$\{1\}=K_n \lhd K_{n-1}
     \lhd \cdots \lhd K_1$$ is a chain of
  normal subgroups. In fact this is an
  upper central series for the group
  $K_1$, i.e $K_{i-1}/K_i = Z(K_1/K_i)$
  and $K_{i-1}/K_i$ is elementary
  abelian of order $p^3$.
- Now $G$ acts naturally on the group
  $K_1$ by conjugation. The upper
  central series structure just
  described implies that this action
  induces an action of $G/K_1 =
     SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ on the
  groups $K_{i-1}/K_i$. Thus the group
  $K_{i-1}/K_i$ becomes a 3-dimensional
  module for the group
  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. It is
  easy to see that for $i=2,\dots, n$,
  these modules are isomorphic. Fact to
  check: This module is irreducible.
- Now let $N$ be a normal subgroup of
  $G$. Suppose first that $N\cap K_1$
  is trivial. Then $N$ is isomorphic to
  a normal subgroup of
  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, i.e.
  $N$ is trivial, equal to $Z$, or
  isomorphic to
  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. In
  the latter case we would have
  $G=K_1\times N$ and it is easy to
  check that this does not happen. Thus
  $N$ is trivial or equal to $Z$.
- Assume next that $N\cap K_1$ is
  non-trivial. In particular $N\cap K_1$ is
  a non-trivial normal subgroup of
  $K_1$. We use the following easy
  fact: *A non-trivial normal subgroup
  of a $p$-group intersects the center
  of that $p$-group non-trivially.* Thus
  $N\cap K_{n-1}$ is non-trivial and is
  a normal subgroup of $G$. But, since
  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ acts
  irreducibly on the module $N\cap
     K_{n-1}$, $N$ must contain $K_{n-1}$.
  If $N\cap K_1 = K_{n-1}$, then there
  are three possibilities for $N$, namely $N=
     K_{n-1}$, $N=K_{n-1} \times Z$ or $N=K_{n-1}.
     SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. If $n=2$, the last possibility corresponds to $G$ and we are done. If $n>2$, then the
  last possibility is impossible just
  as before.
- Now the proof is completed by
  observing that $G/K_{n-1} \cong
     SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z})$ and
  appealing to induction.

**Final remark**: I've read some of Bourgain & Gamburd's work dealing with $SL_2$. They tend to (implicitly) consider the center as a trivial normal subgroup as their work deals with asymptotics on $p$ which are unaffected by $Z$. This explains the apparent inaccuracy of their assertion that the $K_i$ are all of the normal subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Dear Nick: Many thanks for your answer. Do you know any reference which answers this question for general rings? I am in particular interested in the structure of normal subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_k(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n)$, $k\geq 3$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the ring of integer of a non-archimedean local fields of characteristic $0$,  with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Assume that the characteristic of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}$ is not $2$.

Comment: @M.B Sorry, no idea. I don't know anything about the fields you describe...