# List of Conjugacy Classes of the General Linear group over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Does anybody know the answer to this or a good way to go about working this out? I have a list for $GL_2(Z/pZ)$ and I am trying to lift it to this; I have mostly been using fairly elementary algebraic methods. Thank you.

Comment: Steven Sam has a blog post about this at:

http://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/glfq-i-conjugacy-classes-of-a-finite-general-linear-group/

Comment: Note that for this it is really important that it is not just the cyclic group of order $p^2$. It that group with the usual structure of a ring.

Comment: @Tobias, I edited the title to reflect your comment.

Comment: @Gwyn, I think Steven Sam's blogpost only covers conjugacy classes for $GL_2(q)$, i.e. over a finite field. It seems like the MO knows this theory, but is unclear how to lift to the ring $Z/p^2Z$.... I might be wrong!

Comment: Ah, good point. I misread what he was asking for.

Comment: I think Gerald Cliff (possibly with a co-author) may have written about this.

Comment: See also [3] A. Nobs, Die irreduziblen Darstellungen von GL2(Zp) insbesondere GL2(Z2); Math. Ann. 229(1974),
113-133.

Comment: Cassandra Williams's thesis discusses this:  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3078498 and http://search.proquest.com/docview/1069260734.  I can't access it, but this paper of Gregory Hill may be relevant:  http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231615.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to give a full answer now, but here's how I would try and answer this question:

You first need to establish what the normal subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$ are. This is done in a fair amount of detail at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104262/normal-subgroup-of-classical-groups/109886) (at least for $SL_2$, and the same method will generalize to $GL_2$).

Now, as explained in the linked answer above, $G=GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p^3$ which can be thought of as a 3-dimensional module for the group $G/N\cong GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. To get the full-list of conjugacy classes, one needs to examine each coset $gN$ in turn, considering it as a module for the group $C_{G/N}(gN)$.